# notation for precision or number of decimals

Tags: notation

If you have a formula like $x = y+2.1234$, is there a way to specify $y$ should have no more than 2 decimals? So if $y = 12.1234$ then you should use 12.12 when using this formula.

Same for the result, is there a way to specify you only should use the first 2 decimals of $y$ and discard the rest?

To clarify: it is for documentation purposes. I need to document a value should only have 2 decimal places and the rest should be discarded.
So when I have a complex formula $x = ....$, is there any notation possible which shows to use only 2 decimals of $x$?

Comment: Yes - simply write the number with that many decimals, i.e. you just write $12.12$ in the first place.

Comment: Then write another documentation for such notation!

Comment: @MarkMcClure sure but how do you tell you should use only 2 decimals of $x$ ?

Comment: @rve *If* you know that $x$ has $n$ reliable digits, *then* you should write $x$ with $n$ digits. Determination of the number of reliable digits is a different question.

Answer (score -1):

You can write $12.1\bar{2}$ or $12.1\underline{2}$.

edit: I saw this notation on the Khan Academy videos for significant figures.
(He says that it's more common to write the answer in scientific notation and then the precision is implied by how many digits are after the decimal, though).

Comment: can the person who -1'ed this explain why this is bad?

Comment: My guess would be that it's because $12.1\bar2$ could actually mean $12.1222222...$.

Comment: It's also on Wikipedia. I guess that's why both options are used, but consider $12.1\bar{2}0$